# Table head sticky and scroll contents

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

I need to show a table list in such a way that the content should be scrollable keeping the position of table header fixed.IT is working perfectly but the header content is not properly displaying (need to avoid work wrap)

The main problem is while the content is scrolling we could see the scrolling content through a 1px gap somehow created above sticky header.

my code:-

```css
div.list_wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_wrapper col-md-12">
  <div class="table_wrapper table-responsive">
    <table class="">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"></td>
          <td>A text to be always displayed here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let list of OfficersList">
          <td>{{ list.updated_at | date:'d-MM-yyyy' }}</td>
          <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ list.status }}</td>
          <tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I believe my question is clear! please mention any further clarifications needed!Thanks!

Comment: Is this a common issue or cannot be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove space between borders

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
 }
thead tr th {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: i have tried these solutions it is not working for me!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is not behaving as you described. Which is the row you want to be sticky?

As for the problem you have, maybe try with

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: header should be sticky..and body should be scrollable..

Comment: @AmDGrtst have you tried your own code snippet? It's scrolling all for me

Comment: scrolling will work...the issue is not scrolling... i can see the scrolling contents through a 1px gap somehow formed between header and parent div..please check the screenshot!